# ValueError: 21 columns passed, passed data had 20 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, google-colaboratory

My Code is given below :

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = confusion_matrix

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = [i for i in names],
              columns = [i for i in names])
df_norm_col=(df_cm-df_cm.mean())/df_cm.std()
#df_norm_col=df_cm-df_cm.mean()
plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
sn.heatmap(df_norm_col, annot=True,cmap='viridis')
```

and I get the following error:

> ValueError: 21 columns passed, passed data had 20 columns

Comment: Error message suggests DataFrame initialization failed because `array` has a length of 20, while `names` has a length of 21. Both lengths need to match.